# Cocoa Touch NSArray Initialization doesn't work properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

I have several ivar NSArrays that I initialize in my -viewDidLoad method. One contains strings, one contains IBOutlets. However, when I initialize, all of the objects in the array are out of scope, and the memory address is 0x0 (according to the Xcode debugger). However, when I have a local NSArray with the same objects, it works fine. Initializing an ivar NSString or NSDictionary both work fine.

The code:

```
//.h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface myViewController : UIViewController
{
NSArray *myArray;
}
@end

//.m file
#import "myViewController.h"
@implementation myViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aString", @"another string", nil];
    NSLog(@"myArray equals: %@.", myArray);
}
@end
```

When I try using the array, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime error. Is this an Xcode bug, or am I missing something about NSArray? UPDATE: I am using ARC. After I turn ARC off and do a clean build, I no longer get this problem. Is this a bug in ARC?

I don't know what the problem was, but I switched to a stable version of Xcode (4.0.2) and I had NO problems at all. Thanks everyone for trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

That you are using ARC is important to note when asking such a question.

How are you trying to use the array (show the code)?   There is a known bug in certain versions of ARC (which can't be discussed on the iOS side, but the same bug is in the Lion release of ARC) where fast enumeration of a collection under ARC can cause a crash.

Comment: Currently, I am simply trying to NSLog it. The code is `NSLog(@"%@", myArray);`

Comment: Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: I turned ARC off, did a clean build, and I no longer have the problem. Is this an ARC bug, or am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: That sounds like an ARC bug!  Please file it and post the # here.  I'll follow up with the team.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I file a bug report?

Comment: Thanks. #9956752, sorry that I was not able to experiment with other builds/systems to see where the problem came up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the framework has not instantiated the IBOutlet instances yet.  Can you hold off and populate the arrays in the viewWillAppear method?  This will be called before the user sees anything.  Otherwise pull them off of IB, just manage them manually and alloc them at whatever point you want.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with IBOutlet's, because when I have an array with just NSStrings I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code seems to be allocating a new (and local) version of myArray rather than setting the iVar you declare in your header file. Try changing:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aString", @"another string", nil];
```

to

```
myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aString", @"another string", nil];
```

With ARC off, I would presume that any attempt you make to access myArray would do nothing because it would be set to nil and ignore all messages. I'm not sure why this code would work any differently with ARC enabled.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did, I just made a typo. Sorry!

With ARC on, it doesn't work at all. With ARC off, it works fine.